# If $A$ is infinite, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Definition:** A set $A$ is countable if it is finite or if there is a bijection $c: \mathbb N \to A$; otherwise it is uncountable.

> **Theorem**: if $A$ is an infinite set, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is uncountable.

**Cantor’s theorem:** suppose that $f$ is a mapping from a set $A$ to its power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$. Then $f$ is not surjective.

**Lemma 1**: assuming the Axiom of Dependent Choice, if $A$ is an
infinite set, then $A$ contains a countably infinite subset.

**Lemma 2**: $A$ is countable if and only if $A=\emptyset$ or there exists a surjection from $\mathbb N$ onto $A$.

---

The proof is quite short, but I'm not sure if I apply Lemmas correctly. Please help me check it out!

---

Proof: $A$ is an infinite set, then by **Lemma 1** there exists a countably infinite subset $B$ of $A$. Thus there exists a bijection $g: \mathbb N \to B$. Assume the contrary that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is countable, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is countable too. By **Lemma 2**, there exists a surjection $h: \mathbb N \to \mathcal{P}(B)$. As a result, $h \circ g^{-1}: B \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ is surjective. This contradicts Cantor's theorem. Hence $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is uncountable.

Comment: What is your definition of uncountable? Is it that it is strictly larger than $\mathbb N$? If it simply means infinite and not countable (which is the standard usage), then it is easier to prove that if $\mathcal P(A)$ is countable then in fact it is finite. This has the advantage of not using any form of the axiom of choice.

Comment: You're already invoking Cantor's theorem, can't you just say $\aleph_0 \leq |A| < |\mathcal{P}(A)|$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm quite interested in the proof of 'if $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is countable then it is finite', would you mind giving a sketch of it?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo "A set $A$ is countable if it is finite or if there is a bijection $c: \mathbb N \to A$; otherwise it is uncountable." I have edited my post to add this definition.

Comment: @GuidoA. I have added my Cantor's theorem for clarity.

Comment: @LeAnhDung yout theorem states (by definition of the order relation of cardinals) precisely that $|A| < |\mathcal{P}(A)|$ for any set $A$, so you can use the argument above.

Comment: @GuidoA. Oh I got your point. Have you seen any mistake in my proof?

Comment: @LeAnhDung I think it looks fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an infinite set.

It is well known that we can find an injection $\mathbb{N} \to A$. Hence, $|\mathbb{N}| \leq |A|$ and it follows that $$|\mathbb{N}| <|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N)}| \leq |\mathcal{P}(A)|$$

by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: I think we need countable choice for the injection $\mathbb{N} \to A$ though.

Comment: Of course, we do ^^